# Why filter not working on list of strings

Tags: filter, d

I am trying to write code to read a text file and to filter out those lines which have both search items:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string; 
import std.file : readText;
import std.algorithm; 

void main(){
    string[] srchitems = ["second", "pen"];  // to search file text for lines which have both these; 
    auto alltext = readText("testing.txt");
    auto alllist = alltext.split("\n");  
    foreach(str; srchitems){
        alllist = alllist.filter!(a => a.indexOf(str) >= 0);    // not working ;
    }
    writeln(alllist); 
}
```

However, it is not working and giving this error:

```
$ rdmd soq_filter.d 
soq_filter.d(11): Error: cannot implicitly convert expression filter(alllist) of type FilterResult!(__lambda1, string[]) to string[]
Failed: ["/usr/bin/dmd", "-v", "-o-", "soq_filter.d", "-I."]
```

Following line with cast also does not work:

```
    alllist = cast(string[]) alllist.filter!(a => a.indexOf(str) >= 0);     // not working ;
```

Error:

```
Error: cannot cast expression filter(alllist) of type FilterResult!(__lambda1, string[]) to string[]
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have figured out, the return value from `filter` isn't an array, but a custom range. `filter`'s return value is in fact a lazy range, so that if you only use the first few items only those items will be calculated. To convert a lazy range into an array, you will need to use [`std.array.array`](https://dlang.org/library/std/array/array.html):

```
import std.array : array;
alllist = alllist.filter!(a => a.indexOf(str) >= 0).array;
```

In your case, that seems to work well. However, by slightly restructuring your code, there is a more idiomatic solution:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import std.file : readText;
import std.algorithm;
import std.array;

void main() {
    string[] srchitems = ["second", "pen"];
    auto alltext = readText("testing.txt");
    auto alllist = alltext.split("\n");
    auto results = alllist.filter!(a => srchitems.any!(b => a.indexOf(b) >= 0));
    writeln(results);
}
```

In the above code, we use the result of `filter` directly, rather than convert it to an array.